# Valid setup for Reactive data polling in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, polling, reactive

I need to implement periodic polling of some data from remote component.
It should poll data next time **after previous polling is done + wait let's say 5sec**.
I came up with the code below but later figured out app throws Exception upon close - Event viewer has a record for `0xc00000fd` which is stack overflow exception.
It's worth to mention that this exception only happens when app was open and polling data for quite a while (it takes time for stack to overflow).
All this is a WPF app and code below is in `ViewModel`.

I realize why exception is happening in this code (probably shouldn't call OnNext in Subscribe) but what is the correct way to implement?

```
_ctrlSubj = new Subject<ControllerInfo>();
_ctrlSubj.SelectMany(async _ => 
{
    // CurrentController is of type ControllerInfo
    // next line can take various amount of time
    var jobDetails = await Library.GetJobsAsync(CurrentController);
    return jobDetails;
})
.ObserveOnDispatcher()
.Subscribe(async e =>
{
    // Jobs is bound to View
    Jobs = new ObservableCollection<JobDetail>(jobDetails);

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    _ctrlSubj.OnNext(CurrentController);
});
```

Comment: Don't ever do any of this funky recursive `OnNext` code - it'll end in tears. There's almost always a way to write a clean query.

Answer (score 2):

**2nd edit**:

@Aron's answer reminded me of multi subscription problems, which the below answer has. I recommend a helper function `IntervalAsync` looking like this:

```
public static class RxExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<TResult> IntervalAsync<TResult>(Func<IObservable<TResult>> f, TimeSpan period)
    {
        return IntervalAsync(f, period, Scheduler.Default);
    }

    public static IObservable<TResult> IntervalAsync<TResult>(Func<IObservable<TResult>> f, TimeSpan period, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Create<TResult>(o =>
        {
            var q = new BehaviorSubject<TimeSpan>(TimeSpan.Zero);
            var observable = q
                .Delay(t => Observable.Timer(t))
                .SelectMany(_ => f())
                .Do(t => q.OnNext(period));
            return observable.Subscribe(o);
        });
    }
}
```

with the final code looking like this:

```
var subscription = RxExtensions.IntervalAsync(
        () => Observable.FromAsync(() => Library.GetJobsAsync(CurrentController)), 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
    )
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(i =>
    {
        Jobs = new ObservableCollection<JobDetail>(jobDetails);
    });
```

@Aron's answer works. I don't find it simpler because you have more Rx-TPL mixing, though I'l admit that 'simpler' is in the eye of the beholder.

---

**First edit**: (**Not recommended**, multiple subscription bugs are present).

Your concern is valid: With a synchronous reactive pipeline, `Interval` would wait for the full pipeline to finish. But with an async pipeline, `Interval` won't hold up. So if the first async task took 4.5 seconds, the next task would start .5 seconds after the first finished.

If you want the end-to-begin delay to be a set timespan, I think it would be best to do a queueing mechanism, similar to what you set up. I would do something similar to this:

```
var q = new BehaviorSubject<TimeSpan>(TimeSpan.Zero);
var subscription = q
    .Delay(t => Observable.Timer(t))
    .SelectMany(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => Library.GetJobsAsync(CurrentController))
    .Subscribe(i =>
    {
        Jobs = new ObservableCollection<JobDetail>(jobDetails);
    });
```

Rx's thread & stack management I think works better here than TPL, and this won't lead to an infinite stack. However, I haven't tested it.

---

**Original answer:**

This may do it, but I can't test because no types.

```
var subscription = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .SelectMany(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => Library.GetJobsAsync(CurrentController))
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(jobDetails =>
    {
        Jobs = new ObservableCollection<JobDetail>(jobDetails);
    });
```

If no good, then please modify your answer to include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

**Testing code:**

This is the code I'm using to test for async-TPL/RX mix. Doesn't full replicate @IgorStack's environment because no WPF (no `.ObserveOnDispatcher()`):

```
var f = new Func<Task<int>>(async () => {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    return 3;
});

var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(); //or Scheduler.Default
var o1 = RxExtensions.IntervalAsync(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => f()), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), scheduler)
    .Timestamp();
var subscription1 = o1.Subscribe(i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("s1: " + i.Timestamp.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ffff"));
    });
var subscription2 = o1.Subscribe(i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("s2: " + i.Timestamp.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ffff"));
    });
```

Comment: But some calls to `Library.GetJobsAsync(CurrentController)` can take more then 5sec.
What will happen then?

Comment: @IgorStack - The `Observable.Interval` operator provides a way to specify the interval between the end of the last call and the start of the next. It isn't the same as a timer which fires at regular intervals.

Comment: Updated answer. `Interval` doesn't play friendly here because of the async stuff, unless you have some funky scheduler going on. @Enigmativity, if you're thinking scheduler, please post separate answer.

Comment: @Shlomo - Try running it using an `EventLoopScheduler`. That forces it to run on a single thread.

Comment: @Shlomo - Annoying. `Observable.Interval` is meant to work the way I described.

Comment: @Shlomo Sorry dude...there is a simpler solution. Check out `Observable.Create`. This is a helper function that can be used to create a Cold Observable. I tend to use a `while(cancellationToken.IsCancelRequested == false)` in this.

Comment: Updated answer to remove a bug: Also changed design slightly.

Comment: @Shlomo haha, thanks...I haven't done .net in about a year now...Just ran the code in a UnitTest, found that typo too and found it works nicely...:)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry @Shlomo, simplest way to achieve this is the following (this will give you end-to-start delay of 5 seconds).

```
var jobs = Observable.Create<List<Job>>(async (observer, cancel) => {
   while(cancel.IsCancellationRequested == false)
   {
      try
      {
         var ret = await Library.GetJobsAsync(CurrentController);
         observer.OnNext(ret);
         await Task.Delay(5000, cancel);
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         observer.OnError(ex);
         return;
      }
   }
   observer.OnCompleted();

});
```

If instead you want start-to-start delay of 5 seconds you can exchange the body of the code simply with:

```
var delay = Task.Delay(5000, cancel);
var ret = await Library.GetJobsAsync(CurrentController);
observer.OnNext(ret);
await delay;
```

Here is the Code rewritten into a LinqPad "UnitTest"...You can confirm the results.

```
void Main()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    var foo = Observable.Create<int>(async (observer, cancellationToken) => {
        while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested){
            var ret = await DoStuff(scheduler);
            observer.OnNext(ret);
            await Observable.Delay(
                Observable.Return(Unit.Default), 
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 
                scheduler)
            .ToTask();
        }
    });

    using(foo.Timestamp(scheduler).Subscribe(f => Console.WriteLine(f.Timestamp))){
        scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120).Ticks);
    }

}

// Define other methods and classes here


public Task<int> DoStuff(IScheduler scheduler){
    return Observable.Delay(Observable.Return(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), scheduler).ToTask();
}
```

The output is the following:

```
01/01/0001 00:00:01 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:00:07 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:00:13 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:00:19 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:00:25 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:00:31 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:00:37 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:00:43 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:00:49 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:00:55 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:01:01 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:01:07 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:01:13 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:01:19 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:01:25 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:01:31 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:01:37 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:01:43 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:01:49 +00:00
01/01/0001 00:01:55 +00:00
```